# How to setup nginx config for flask app when flask has api object initialised with prefix parameter

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-location, nginx-config, flask-restplus

I have flask app running using blueprint and api object initialised with prefix of `api`

```
api = Api(_bp, catch_all_404s=True, prefix="/api", version=0.1,
          title="Clinical record management REST HTTP API's Gateway",
          descrition="REST API gateway for Clinical Record Management.")
```

and I have setup nginx configuration for my site

```
location /api {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri @wsgi;
}
```

but navigating to location `ipAddress/api` doesn't work

I get errr saying :

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: I have worked on this problem today. I can't really give a proper and full explanation, but doing `location /api/` instead of `location /api` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @IMCoins I gave it a try now I am getting a different error saying ‘{"message": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. You have requested this URI [/api/] but did you mean /api or /static/<path:filename> ?"}‘

Comment: I removed catch_all_404s=True, from my flask app and now I am seeing bad gateway error